# Can I project one subspace onto another?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I learnt today in class that I can project a vector onto a subspace. Now it seems obvious to me that I should be able to project any scalar multiple of this same vector onto the subspace which is basically projecting a line onto this subspace. So in general can I project any subspace(a line in my example) onto any other subspace?

Comment: Yes. By linearity of the projection operator, you can easily check that you obtain a linear subspace of the subspace on which you project.

Comment: Is there a general procedure or even a wikipedia page which explains it in terms that a first-year could understand? I googled but the only results were for projecting a single vector onto a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we want to project subspace $X$ onto subspace $Y$ (both subspaces of $V$). There is a complementary subspace $Z$ such that $V=Y\oplus Z$. Then the map $\pi : V \rightarrow Y$ given by $\pi(y+z)=y$ is a linear transformation, so $\pi(X)$ is a subspace of $Y$.